# How do I get my heroku app's node version?

Tags: node.js, heroku, heroku-cli, dyno

Is there a way to see which version of node your app on heroku is using?

I saw that you can specify the version of node

```
"engines": {
    "node": "14.x"
  },
```

I have not specified a node version this way. But my app was giving me errors as if it was an old version of node where the memory limit is 512mb even though my dyno has a 1gb memory.

```
Mark-sweep 505.7 (522.4) -> 502.2 (523.1) MB, 440.3 / 0.0 ms  (average mu = 0.280, current mu = 0.148) allocation failure scavenge might not succeed
```

So is there a way to see what version of node my heroku app is using?

Comment: At runtime of your node app you can use [`process.version`](https://nodejs.org/api/process.html#processversion)

Answer (score 3):

You can find something like `Downloading and installing node 16.17.0..` in the **build log**.

1. go to https://dashboard.heroku.com/apps/**yourapp**
2. Under "Latest Activity" find a build that says "Build succeeded"
3. click "View build log"
4. look for something like `Downloading and installing node 16.17.0..`